realloc(ptr, 0) in C23 - now what?
According to the change log of C23, proposal n2464 was voted-in and implemented, making realloc(ptr, 0) explicitly undefined behavior, whereas it was supposedly implementation-defined in previous standards. In the drafts (quotes are from n3096), the specification of realloc has been changed accordingly: (bold emphasis mine)

7.24.3.7 The realloc function
/--/
...or if the size is zero, the behavior is undefined

However, in the C23 drafts we can also read:

7.24.3 Memory management functions
/--/
If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
implementation-defined


Annex J.1 Unspecified behavior
(46) The amount of storage allocated by a successful call to the calloc, malloc, realloc, or
aligned_alloc function when 0 bytes was requested (7.24.3).


Annex J.2 Undefined behavior
(179) A non-null pointer returned by a call to the calloc, malloc, realloc, or aligned_alloc
function with a zero requested size is used to access an object (7.24.3).


Annex J.3.12 Implementation-defined behavior
(42) Whether the calloc, malloc, realloc, and aligned_alloc functions return a null pointer or
a pointer to an allocated object when the size requested is zero (7.24.3).

Now, I did try to point out this defect to the ISO C WG through informal channels, but to deaf ears evidently, since the defects are still there in draft n3220. 7.24.3.7 and 7.24.3 are both normative texts, whereas Annex J is informative (and already filled to the brim with errors even before C23, never to be trusted). So which of the contradicting texts is "most normative"?
May old programs with realloc(ptr, 0) get ported to C23 and the same implementation-defined behavior might still be there? Or will such code be non-portable to C23 since it invokes UB? Or will this remain a defect after publication and we have to wait for a TC to get published?

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3p.html#FUTURE_DIRECTIONS <- POSIX.1‐2017 has some foreshadowing in the Future Directions section, so the plan and intention seem to be to discourage this

@teapot418 C17 has the same text in future library extensions. It does seem quite clear that the intention was always to make it UB, but they really made a mess when editing.

You've missed the boat for public comments on C23 now.

@IanAbbott I first reported this in May 2023, but by e-mail. Maybe it got lost in cyberspace.

Is this the right site to ask such questions? -- And if so, why?

You would have to go through your national standards body, not through ISO.

@thebusybee With some luck it reaches the ears of the right person. Or perhaps this is a known DR, I wouldn't know.

@IanAbbott Yeah I probably picked the wrong ivory tower. However, the fact remains that the ISO 9899 proposal looks like it was edited by someone under the influence. And that's not really my problem, but a problem that the ISO WG should be interested to learn about.

One clear inference is that portable code should not attempt to request zero bytes from the memory allocation functions.  Whatever is returned cannot be accessed anyway.

@JonathanLeffler Seems like plenty of code bases did this (with malloc & realloc both) for various questionable purposes. I see questions pop up on SO about it now and then. But back when it was truly implementation-defined, a certain compiler might have produced a certain documented result from it. What will happen in C23 seems to be anyone's guess, however.

I guess 7.24.3 could do with a footnote, and Annex J.2 ought to mention the new UB in realloc somewhere, perhaps by modiying J.2 (179) or by adding a separate item. J.1 (46), and J.3.12 (42) still apply when realloc is called with a null pointer, so are probably fine.

@IanAbbott The main issue is that 7.24.3 and 7.24.3.7 contradict each other.

We don't yet have the official ISO/IEC 9899:2024 document yet — as of 2024-07-01T08:15:00-06:00, you can purchase the DIS for 129 CHF.  So there might (but probably won't) be changes we can't see.

@JonathanLeffler A "redline version" with all changes would be handy for sure, I wonder if they plan to publish something like that.

7.24.3 discusses allocation of objects. It could be argued that realloc(ptr, 0); (for a non-null ptr) has already hit UB before it tries to allocate anything.

@IanAbbott It clearly says that doing so is implementation-defined and one of several documented behaviors is a possibility.

7.24.3 also fails to mention the other ways that calls to realloc result in UB, but you do not seem to be complaining about that.

Semi-tangentially: any idea what the new functions §7.24.3.4 free_sized and §7.24.3.5 free_aligned_sized functions defined in n3096 from 2023-04-01 or n3220 from 2024-02-22 are for?  If you use them correctly, they behave like free(); otherwise, the behaviour is undefined.  There's no way to find out whether you used them correctly.  Those seem peculiarly useless to me.  Does anyone have a rationale (or a link to the document where they were introduced)?

As Steven Maguire pointed out in Writing Solid Code: 20th Anniversary 2nd Edn (2013), it used to be that realloc() is an 'all-in-one' memory management function.  It can allocate memory, shrink already allocated memory, expand already allocated memory, or free already allocated memory — so why bother with malloc() or free().  It isn't completely clear that the C standard fully approved this, but it was close to reality on many systems.  The general direction (intention) has been to tighten up the semantics.

@JonathanLeffler See N2699 for the initial free_sized and free_aligned_sized proposal.

IMO: Well defined free(0) is a nice feature of free(), else users need to code if (ptr) free(ptr).  Re-defining ID behavior of realloc(ptr, 0) to UB is a wrong direction and makes for more complex (and more error prone) usage of realloc() as well as malloc().  Just leave (re-)allocation of zero as ID behavior and stop breaking existing code bases for little, if any gain.

@IanAbbott: Thanks.  I am surprised that the 'UB on erroneous usage' decision was accepted.  But then again, if you pass invalid data to free(), that is UB too. I suppose that if the implementation benefits from being told the size, then the new functions give an advantage, but it feels uncomfortable to me.  I am not going to hasten to use those functions.

I feel like the real answer here is that it doesn't make any sense to call realloc(x, 0), it never made sense as it is ambiguous, and this should be a wake up call for anyone that does use it to refactor their code. :')

@MarcoBonelli Plenty of code out there which only ever works with realloc and not malloc, initializing pointers to point to allocated memory of zero size. Not the best idea perhaps, but common enough.

With C23's release , is the matter still open?  (I.e. any wording change in the true spec?)

I'm not 100% sure, but a quite reasonable analogy comes from law. In law, there is a doctrine called "lex specialis" which means that specific rules takes precedence over general ones, under the assumption that those who wrote one of them was aware of the other.
Following this principle, the behaviour should be undefined, since a rule that specifically addresses the realloc function is more specific than "memory management functions"
